Regex pattern for different date formats does not seem to capture all desired cases
I am trying to process a txt file line per line to find date information in different patterns and write them to a consistent YYYY, YYYY-MM and YYYY-MM-DD format.
My input formats across different lines of narrative text are:
1) YYYY, e.g. 1890
2) MM.YYYY, e.g. 10.1765
3) M.YYYY, e.g. 9.1700
4) DD.MM.YYYY, e.g. 11.11.1876
5) D.MM.YYYY, e.g. 9.10.1678
6) D.M.YYYY, e.g. 9.1.1768
7) DD.M.YYYY, e.g. 21.3.1789
8) DD.MM., e.g. 12.12. (no year)
9) D.M., e.g. 1.1. (no year)

In context, the concerned lines typically look like this:
"7.1.1695 jur. geprüft"
"12.1. verteidigt unter v. Haaren"
"ord. [Weihe] Mainz 21.9.1743"
"erhielt 1786 die Pfarrei Irmstraut (Diöz. Trier)"
"ein Anton Alperstätt 20.9. 1748 bacc."


I have been trying to write a regex pattern that captures as many of these cases as possible and replaces the identified strings (extracted from a more extended code) with my desired output formats:
    def replace_dates(merged_lines):
        def format_date(search):
            year = ""
            month = ""
            day = ""
            # check how many groups are in the pattern
            num_groups = search.groups()
            print(num_groups)
            if len(num_groups) == 0:
                year = "0000"
            if len(num_groups) == 1:
                year = search.group(0)
                print(year)
            elif 2 < len(num_groups) <= 4:
                day = search.group(1) if search.group(1) else '00'
                month = search.group(3) if search.group(3) else '00'
            elif num_groups == 5:
                day = search.group(1) if search.group(1) else '00'
                month = search.group(3) if search.group(3) else '00'
                year = search.group(5)

            # determine the output format
            if month != '00' and day != '00':
                return f"{year}-{month}-{day}"  # Format: YYYY-MM-DD
            elif month != '00':
                return f"{year}-{month}"         # Format: YYYY-MM
            else:
                return year                      # Format: YYYY

        # Compile regex pattern
        date_pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(\d{1,2})([.-]|\s)?(\d{1,2})?([.-]|\s)?(\d{4})(?!\d)')

        #Group 1: day (1 or 2 digits)
        #Group 2: separator between day and month (if present)
        #Group 3: month (1 or 2 digits)
        #Group 4: separator between month and year (if present)
        #Group 5: year (4 digits)

        replaced_lines = []

        for line in merged_lines:
            if line.startswith("[Source]"):
                replaced_lines.append(line)
            else:
                searches = date_pattern.finditer(line)
                for search in searches:
                    line = line.replace(search.group(0), format_date(search))
                replaced_lines.append(line)

        return replaced_lines

Looking at the searches that are being captured, however, I have several issues:

Instances where only the year is present are somehow being ignored.
Cases where I have time ranges in my data, e.g. "1786-1790", are retrieved as ('17', None, '86', '-', '1790').

If more than one date is in each row, I would gladly only process the first one to keep things simple. I have also considered abandoning the idea of a single regex and processing each case separately, but I fear this would make the script unnecessarily complex.

Regular expressions are a crude tool for something as complex as date formats.

Please add a sample of text for each case

No text before dates? how year is replaced or handled if missing?

Because I am working with historical dates in all the non-machine-readable formats, I thought that treating them as strings and working with regular expressions was my best bet. I have added examples of how the dates are integrated into the original text. Dates can come up anywhere in the line. If there is no date, I want to copy the existing line without processing.

you can use a regexp to find a sequence of numbers and . with [\d.]+. Once you have that, use split() to split it at the . separators, and use Python logic to decide which case it is.

Can the text contain numbers that aren't dates? How will you distinguish that?

Another suggestion is to make the regex correspond exactly to the definition you've given with the cases separated by alternation. This is more readable and understandable than trying to factor across cases. When one case is a common prefix of another, be sure to put it after.  So ... \d{4}|\d{2}\.\d{4}|... . There will be a small performance penalty compared to fancy forms, but probably not significant. The sites that let you fiddle with a regex on line are great for checking yours works as intended.

@Gene, actually, this is the solution I have been working on in the past hour. The results are better, but I still cannot capture all cases. But I think there are just two many exceptions to handle via script. Perhaps something for manual labour.

Based on your sample data, you could use this regex to match your dates:
(?<!\d)(?=\d)(?:(?P<day>\d\d?)\.)?(?:(?P<month>\d\d?)\.)?(?P<year>\d{4})?(?!\d)

This matches:

(?<!\d)(?=\d) : negative lookbehind for a digit and positive lookahead for a digit; this ensures our match starts at the beginning of a sequence of digits
(?:(?P<day>\d\d?)\.)? : optional day number followed by .
(?:(?P<month>\d\d?)\.)? : optional month number followed by .
(?P<year>\d{4})? : optional year
(?!\d) : negative lookahead for a digit - this ensures that one of the optional groups must match because of the positive lookahead for a digit at the beginning of the regex

Regex demo on regex101
Once you've captured the groups, you can then reformat the values to YYYY-MM-DD format:
lines = [
    "7.1.1695 jur. geprüft",
    "12.1. verteidigt unter v. Haaren",
    "ord. [Weihe] Mainz 21.9.1743",
    "erhielt 1786 die Pfarrei Irmstraut (Diöz. Trier)",
    "ein Anton Alperstätt 20.9. 1748 bacc."
]

def formatter(m):
    formats = { 'year' : 4, 'month' : 2, 'day' : 2 }
    parts = [ f'{m.group(g).zfill(formats[g])}' for g in formats if m.group(g) ]
    return '-'.join(parts)

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d)(?:(?P<day>\d\d?)\.)?(?:(?P<month>\d\d?)\.)?(?P<year>\d{4})?(?!\d)')

for line in lines:
    print(pattern.sub(formatter, line))

Output:
1695-01-07 jur. geprüft
01-12 verteidigt unter v. Haaren
ord. [Weihe] Mainz 1743-09-21
erhielt 1786 die Pfarrei Irmstraut (Diöz. Trier)
ein Anton Alperstätt 09-20 1748 bacc.


Given the provided samples and adding a few others
import re
from datetime import datetime

lpatt = r"^(.+ )?([0-9]{1,2}\.)([0-9]{1,2}\.){0,2}( ?[0-9]{4})?( .+)?$"

cpatt = re.compile(lpatt)

lines = [
    "asd 1.12.1698 dssd asdasd",
    "fdsfd 3.1254 cdcd sss",
    "some 31.12.1600 next",
    "some 7.1.1492 next",
    "some 31.12. next",
    "some next",
    "7.1.1695 jur. geprüft",
    "12.1. verteidigt unter v. Haaren",
    "ord. [Weihe] Mainz 21.9.1743",
    "erhielt 1786 die Pfarrei Irmstraut (Diöz. Trier)",
    "ein Anton Alperstätt 20.9. 1748 bacc."
]

for current in lines:
    result = cpatt.findall(current)
    if len(result) == 0:
        print(current)
        continue
    
    dparts = [ p for p in result[0][1:4] if p != '' ]
    infmt = ''
    outfmt = ''
    date_str = ''
    #print(dparts)
    if len(dparts) == 2 and len(dparts[1]) < 4:
        infmt = "%d.%m."
        outfmt = "%m-%d"
        date_str = f"{dparts[0]}{dparts[1]}"
    elif len(dparts) == 2 and len(dparts[1]) == 4:
        infmt = "%m.%Y"
        outfmt = "%Y-%m"
        date_str = f"{dparts[0]}{dparts[1]}"
    elif len(dparts) == 3:
        year = dparts[2].replace(' ', '')
        infmt = "%d.%m.%Y"
        outfmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
        date_str = f"{dparts[0]}{dparts[1]}{year}"
    
    dfmt = datetime.strptime(date_str, infmt).strftime(outfmt)
    print(f"{result[0][0]}{dfmt}{result[0][4]}")

Result
asd 1698-12-01 dssd asdasd
fdsfd 1254-03 cdcd sss
some 1600-12-31 next
some 1492-01-07 next
some 12-31 next
some next
1695-01-07 jur. geprüft
01-12 verteidigt unter v. Haaren
ord. [Weihe] Mainz 1743-09-21
erhielt 1786 die Pfarrei Irmstraut (Diöz. Trier)
ein Anton Alperstätt 1748-09-20 bacc.

